# Rotate node around y axis considering euler values in scene kit iOS

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I want to rotate a node in y axis which has euler x value -90 (x:0,y:0,z:0). How can i achieve this? I have checked other posts related to rotation but all solutions are provided for euler values (0,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

Don't rotate the around (0, 1, 0) but rotate this vector by multiplying it to the nodes `transform`. For `eulerAngles` of (-90, 0, 0) this results in the axis (0.0, -0.448074, 0.893997).
But I assume you actually want the euler angles set to -90° (all angles are in radians in SceneKit), wich results in the axis (0, 0, 1), so you need to rotate the node around the z-axis of the rotated node.

You can also wrap your node with your euler angles set in a parent node and rotate this parent node around the y-axis and let SceneKit handle the transformations and coordinate spaces.

Comment: I know this comment is hella old, but would you be able to show some code for this type of issue? I'm having a hell of a time doing this myself.